# Line Reading in Python, list variable for line treated as integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I have that code in **python 3.2**

```
infile = self._handle_bom(infile)
for line in infile:
    if (not line) or (line[-1] not in ('\r', '\n', '\r\n')):   # <- error here
        continue
    for end in ('\r\n', '\n', '\r'):
        if line.endswith(end):
            self.newlines = end
            break
    break
```

Have an error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is python treating line as an int?

**EDIT:**
Ok, looks like I'm in a way more complicated stuff.

`_handle_bom` was a class function that handled BOM. I'm not familiar with chartypes but following all the other methods it seems that finally infile is returned as decoded by .decode(different types of stuff).

Comment: any chance `infile` is a list of integers? i would make a `print infile` just before this loop

Comment: Are you sure `infile` is a file handle and not a string/list/something else?  Perhaps post a sample of `infile`.

Comment: Post more of your code...

Comment: Oops you guys are right looks like infile was converted or something. Missed it. Still I wonder how this code worked on Python2.x and not in Python3.x?

Comment: also, `line[-1] not in (..., '\r\n')` looks strange

Answer (score 1):

Doubtless your problem is actually in the `_handle_bom` routine.

But this logic is also redundant.

```
if (not line) or (line[-1] not in ('\r', '\n', '\r\n')):
```

That says, "if the line is empty (or None, or 0, or [] or {})  or does not end in a newline character, continue the loop"

```
for end in ('\r\n', '\n', '\r'):
    if line.endswith(end):
        break
```

This duplicates the second half of the previous if statement.

---

That aside, this code actually answers this question:

> What kind of newline characters does the first non-blank line in this file end with?

Which could be re-written like so:

```
def get_newline_type(self, lines):
    for line in lines:
        if line:
            # Prevents your TypeError, but your BOM code probably shouldn't be
            # returning non-string lines anyway?
            line = str(line) 
            newline_types = filter(lambda x: line.endswith(x), ('\r\n', '\r', '\n'))
            if newline_types:
                return newline_types[0]
            else:
                return None
```

Then you could simply call it like so:

```
self.newline_type = self.get_newline_type(self._handle_bom(infile))
```

Of course there's another question here - do you actually want `self.newlines` to be None (or in your case, whatever it was set to before that code was called) if the first non-blank line doesn't end with `'\r\n', '\n', or '\r'`? If it doesn't matter because there will never be one of those lines, or you do in fact want the EOL character(s), simply remove the else condition.

Comment: Side note: `endswith` accepts a tuple, so `line.endswith(('\r\n', '\n', '\r'))` works as you'd guess.